# The image should not be deleted but it is, why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

```
exports.onWriteCancelExtraStorage = functions.database.ref("users/{userID}").onWrite((snapshot,context) => {
    const dues = snapshot.after.val();
    const userID = context.params.userID
    const query = {
           directory: userID+"/images/"
    };
    return admin.storage().bucket().getFiles(query,function(err, files) {
          if (!err) {
                  return files.forEach(function(file) {
                    var boolIfFindend = false
                    if (snapshot.after.exists()) {
                    snapshot.after.forEach(function (childSnapshot){
                    const imageName = childSnapshot.key;
                        if (childSnapshot.child("serviceImageUrl").val() === file.name) {
                  console.log("Trovata l'immagine "+ file.name)
                              boolIfFindend = true
                        }
                });
                if (boolIfFindend === false) {
                    console.log("Questa immagine è da eliminare perchè non è stata trovata : "+file.name);
            file.delete()
                } else {
                    console.log("Questa immagine non è da eliminare perchè è stata trovata : "+file.name);
                }}
                });
            } else {
                console.log(err)
                return 0
            }

    });
});
```

Logs :

Questa immagine non è da eliminare

immediately after

Questa immagine è da eliminare

I'm trying to clean the database from the images that remain alone and not tied to any data in the database. It actually works well, but something goes wrong from time to time.

The image is evaluated twice in succession generating two different and opposite consecutive logs, there must be an error in the cycle that causes the image to be evaluated first as not to be deleted and then as to be deleted, when in fact it shouldn't be evaluated twice, the database is ok and they are  sure that the image should not be deleted because the data that binds it exists in the database.

The image should not be deleted but is still deleted. Why?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what isn't working the way you expect.  Please update the question to be more specific about the case where the file is deleted where it shouldn't be.  We should be able to reproduce the situation given what you provide in the question.

Comment: Question updated is ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Two subscriptions were saved in the database, this meant that when the first "onWrite" started, it found the second subscription still not fully loaded in the database and deleted the image of the second, I solved by working on the metadata dates of the file and not deleting  files updated less than a day before!